# unhealthy instances:1 cross region load balancing

Tags: gcloud

I have configured cross region load balancing b/w two instances. One is of region us-central1-a and other one I created is of asia region. After doing all configurations, I see one instance unhealthy as other one is fine.

Same configurations I performed with instances of asia and europe region, both are not functioning properly as they are unhealthy. I am guessing that this is configurable in US regions only.

Could you please explain me the cause of issue.
++++
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects
  port: 80
kind: compute#backendServiceGroupHealth
+++++

Comment: Can I get a situation if that's possible what I am doing.

Comment: is HTTP service is running on both instances on port 80?

Comment: I too am having this issue where the LB interface says my instances are unhealthy with a [!] icon by the instances in question, though they are actually up and running just fine...